# Union two ImmutableEnumSets with Guava

Tags: java, guava, immutability, enumset

I want to union two `ImmutableEnumSets` from Guava.
Here's my try on it:

```
public final class OurColors {

    public enum Colors {
        RED,
        GREEN,
        BLUE,
        YELLOW,
        PINK,
        BLACK
    }

    public final static ImmutableSet<Colors> myColorSet =
            Sets.immutableEnumSet(Colors.BLUE,
                                  Colors.GREEN);

    public final static ImmutableSet<Colors> yourColorSet =
            Sets.immutableEnumSet(Colors.YELLOW,
                                  Colors.PINK);

    public final static ImmutableSet<Colors> ourColorSet =
            Sets.union(myColorSet, ourColorSet);
}
```

The field `ourColorSet` does not compile, it fails with

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from Sets.SetView<OurColors.Colors> to
ImmutableSet<OurColors.Colors>
```

How is the union done correct?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, `Sets.union` returns a `Sets.SetView<E>`, not an `ImmutableSet<E>`. So you can do this:

```
public final static Sets.SetView<Colors> ourColorSet =
        Sets.union(myColorSet, yourColorSet);
```

... which in many cases would be fine, or use `Set` instead:

```
public final static Set<Colors> ourColorSet =
        Sets.union(myColorSet, yourColorSet);
```

That's still going to be unmodifiable, it just doesn't have the compile-time type of being `ImmutableSet<E>`. If you really, really need that, you can use `immutableCopy()`:

```
public final static ImmutableSet<Colors> ourColorSet =
        Sets.union(myColorSet, yourColorSet).immutableCopy();
```

... or to create another enum-aware set:

```
public final static ImmutableSet<Colors> ourColorSet =
        Sets.immutableEnumSet(Sets.union(myColorSet, yourColorSet));
```

Comment: Thx. I need the performance of EnumSets and the immutability. So your second proposal is what I need.

Comment: @juxeii: Note that you don't have an `EnumSet` there - just an `ImmutableSet`. If you need an `EnumSet` you'll need a different approach - I'm editing my answer.